# System.getenv() only works properly when debugging IntelliJ plugin

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I'm running IntelliJ 13 (on OS X Yosemite) and trying to get the [Go IDEA plugin](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin) working. When I debugged the application to try to find what the problem is, I found that for some reason the slave IDEA that's ran gets my environment just fine.

Normally when trying to run anything involving the `go` utility, an exception is thrown. The plugin will execute commands by executing `go <args>` with the environment vars:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec(command, goEnv, new File(projectDir));
```

If I change the `go` command to be the full path of the `go` binary, all works fine. When debugging however, I don't have to change the path and it still succeeds.

The plugin has an [action which prints out the environment](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/blob/886aac7c9ab5b3209fde3a912dc904a63a6cf19a/src/ro/redeul/google/go/ide/actions/GoDebugSysEnv.java#L49) which calls `System.getenv()`

```
GoToolWindow toolWindow = this.getGoToolWindow(project);
toolWindow.showAndCreate(project);
toolWindow.clearConsoleView();

String[] sysEnv = GoSdkUtil.convertEnvMapToArray(System.getenv());


toolWindow.printNormalMessage(String.format("%s -> %s%n", "Project dir", projectDir));
for (String env : sysEnv) {
    toolWindow.printNormalMessage(String.format("%s%n", env));
}
```

When running IDEA normally, this outputs:

```
Project dir -> /Users/lander/Development/downloader
SHELL=/bin/zsh
TMPDIR=/var/folders/6y/xxqr1vqn6q7c_ttvdgjt7p1w0000gn/T/
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
USER=lander
HOME=/Users/lander
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=com.jetbrains.intellij.43484
LOGNAME=lander
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.tV9zH4QXK4/Render
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.BCyPknIo2V/Listeners
```

And when debugging the plugin:

```
Project dir -> /Users/lander/IdeaProjects/gotest
ZSH=/Users/lander/.oh-my-zsh
com.apple.java.jvmMode=client
GREP_OPTIONS=--color=auto --exclude-dir=.cvs --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_14389=com.intellij.idea.Main
LOGNAME=lander
GREP_COLOR=1;32
ZSH_TMUX_TERM=screen
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.BCyPknIo2V/Listeners
OLDPWD=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13.app/Contents/bin
SHELL=/bin/zsh
LC_CTYPE=
TMPDIR=/var/folders/6y/xxqr1vqn6q7c_ttvdgjt7p1w0000gn/T/
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/texbin:/Users/lander/go/bin
VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION=2.7
GOPATH=/Users/lander/go
LESS=-R
USER=lander
com.apple.java.jvmTask=CommandLine_Manual.java
ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTARTED=true
PAGER=less
HOME=/Users/lander
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.tV9zH4QXK4/Render
LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
_ZSH_TMUX_FIXED_CONFIG=/Users/lander/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/tmux/tmux.extra.conf
VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=no
```

What's the reason for the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a [JetBrains employee](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131091), this is because the slave instance is launched with the environment given by an external script that's ran. Plugins in the parent process should not call `System.getenv()` and instead use the `EnvironmentUtil`.